# parsing a string into two part with Split method

Tags: java, split

I was parsing a string into 2 parts partitioned by the 1st appearance of the `'&'` character. For example: if the string is `555&hello &world` the partitions will be `555` and `hello &world`. I used following code:

```
String[] numberAndMessage=currentMessage.split("(\\&)",2);
System.out.println(numberAndMessage[1]+storedMessage.message+"end");
```

So, with input: `555&hello &world`

The output I expected was: `hello &worldend`

But instead it gave: `hello &world`

Maybe any problem in the ending character of 2nd partition.
But what is the problem?

**The code:**

UDPServer.java:

```
import java.net.*;
public class UDPServer extends Thread{
    public void run(){
        try{
            DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9999);
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            while(true)
            {
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                String currentMessage = new String( receivePacket.getData());
                System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + currentMessage);
                String[] numberAndMessage=currentMessage.split("(\\&)", 2);
                System.out.println("noAndMessage[0]="+numberAndMessage[0]+";noAndMessage[1]="+numberAndMessage[1]);
                System.out.println("numberAndMessage[1]=    "+numberAndMessage[1]+"end");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        UDPServer server=new UDPServer();
        server.start();
    }
}
```

UDPClient.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class UDPClient
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader inFromUser =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        sendData = sentence.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9999);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Input at UDPClient.java:

```
555&hello world
```

Output at UDPServer.java:

```
RECEIVED: 555&hello world
noAndMessage[0]=555;noAndMessage[1]=hello world
numberAndMessage[1]=    hello world
```

Comment: Could be a null (0) character?

Comment: java arrays are indexed from 0. And, you're not telling the truth. Your output will always end with "end". And, you're hiding code rgd. `storedMessage`

Comment: what you mean storedMessage?

Comment: The code provided will add `end` to the end. Please construct a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem (with the emphasis on **self-contained**).

Comment: I provided the full code and console output now.cant solve the problem yet :(

Comment: Try adding this to your program: `System.out.println("RECEIVED LEN: " + currentMessage.length()); for (char c: currentMessage.toCharArray()) System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(c));` to see if there's any weird characters at the end that may cause this. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) to see what the outputted values mean.

Comment: What java version is this? I remember that with early (beta?) versions of JDK7, there was a bug that caused parts of the output not to  appear.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about `storedMessage.message` .but following code works good for you expecting output.

```
    String  currentMessage="555&hello &world";
    String[] numberAndMessage=currentMessage.split("(\\&)",2);
    System.out.println(numberAndMessage[1]+"end");
```

here you will get OUtPUT:

```
hello &worldend
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    String currentMessage = "555&hello &world";
    String[] numberAndMessage = currentMessage.split("(\\&)", 2);
    System.out.println(numberAndMessage[1] + "end");
  }
}
```

output

```
hello &worldend
```

for your full code I got this following result

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

public class UDPServer extends Thread{

  public void run(){
      try{
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9999);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        String a = "555&hello world";
        receiveData = a.getBytes();
        while(true)
        {

            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            //serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String currentMessage = new String( receivePacket.getData());
            System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + currentMessage);
            String[] numberAndMessage=currentMessage.split("(\\&)", 2);
            System.out.println("noAndMessage[0]="+numberAndMessage[0]+";noAndMessage[1]="+numberAndMessage[1]);
            System.out.println("numberAndMessage[1]=    "+numberAndMessage[1]+"end");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
    UDPServer server=new UDPServer();
    server.start();
  }
}
```

Output is

```
RECEIVED: 555&hello world
noAndMessage[0]=555;noAndMessage[1]=hello world
numberAndMessage[1]=    hello worldend
```

Comment: I got a result of `RECEIVED: 555&hello world
noAndMessage[0]=555;noAndMessage[1]=hello world
numberAndMessage[1]=    hello worldend` from your full code.